# Multi-line texts in xticklabel from a File in PGFplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using LaTeX, TikZ and PGFplots to generate a bar chart, in which the `xticklabel` is read from `testdata.dat` file.

In the following example, the `xticklabel` is a single line, i.e., `Big-Bed, Small-Bed`. Now I want to change them to two-line texts i.e. `Big \\ Bed, Small \\ Bed`  respectively.

Unfortunately, when replacing `-` with `\\` in `testdata.dat`, I found that there are some errors in compiling. Maybe `\\` is not allowed in `testdat.dat` by `fileconcents`. Could anyone kindly help me out to change the `xticklabel` text into two-line texts?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{filecontents} 


\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat} 
Label X-Position Height 
Big-Bed    1    15 
Small-Bed    2    20 
\end{filecontents}

% 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
    ybar, 
    xtick=data,% crucial line for the xticklabels directive 
    ymin=0, 
    xticklabels from table={testdata.dat}{Label} 
] 

\addplot table [ 
    x=X-Position, 
    y=Height 
] {testdata.dat}; 

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use line breaks in node names you have to let TikZ switch to some sort of text formatting mode. The easiest is to make an alignment declaration such that it pays attention to the content. Also you can put braces around sensitive node cell contents to protect them (has some limitations probably)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{filecontents} 


\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat} 
Label X-Position Height 
{Big\\BedHotel\\\$\$} 1 15 
{Small\\Bed\&Breakfast} 2 20 
\end{filecontents}

% 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
    ybar, 
    xtick=data,% crucial line for the xticklabels directive 
    ymin=0, 
    xticklabels from table={testdata.dat}{Label},
        xticklabel style={align=center}
] 

\addplot table [ 
    x=X-Position, 
    y=Height 
] {testdata.dat}; 

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: note that defining `xticklabel style` is essential to avoid an error