# Histogram Excel-like

Tags: pgfplots, histogram

I am a newbie with pgfplots so, after searching on internet and on pdf manuals, I am asking here. I need to reproduce with LaTeX some graphics like this one I made with Excel, can anyone help me with the code?
[image: graphic excel-like]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Moreover, there are many posts about histogram here, have you searched?

Comment: You will find a lot of answers on this site for your problem when you search for `[pgfplots][bar-chart] ...` which brings up a result like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101320/grouped-bar-chart which should pretty much answer all your needs, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many plots [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html). For your example you have to set some option. (The used percent sign solution  for ticklabel you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87431/124842).)

**Modifications:**

```
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
xtick = data,
ytick={0,10,...,60},
enlarge y limits=0.0,
ymax=60,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
anchor=north,legend columns=-1}, 
ybar=5pt,
bar width=10pt, 
symbolic x coords={PC,PML,RR,PN},
ymajorgrids,
ticklabel style = {color=gray},% or opacity=0.5
axis line style={draw=none},
tick style={draw=none},
legend style={draw=none,text=gray}
 ]
```

[Redefinition of the legend image code for a single ybar legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224677/124842):

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
   },
}
```

**Solution**
[image]

**MWE:**

```
 \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
   },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
xtick = data,
ytick={0,10,...,60},
enlarge y limits=0.0,
ymax=60,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
anchor=north,legend columns=-1}, 
ybar=5pt,
bar width=10pt, 
symbolic x coords={PC,PML,RR,PN},
ymajorgrids,
ticklabel style = {color=gray},% or opacity=0.5
axis line style={draw=none},
tick style={draw=none},
legend style={draw=none,text=gray}
 ]
 \addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates {(PC,52) (PML,5) (RR,0) (PN,42) };
 \addplot[yellow,fill=yellow] coordinates {(PC,38) (PML,8) (RR,2) (PN,52) }; 
 \legend{A,B} 
 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: 
You can use `width` and long text like `PC personal computer`.Mabe you will rotate (`rotate=0` or `rotate=45`) the labels. Then you have to change the  `anchor=north east`. Maybe optional xshift... :

```
symbolic x coords={PC personal computer,PML,RR,PN},
xticklabels   = {PC personal computer, PML, RP, PN},
x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=north, inner sep=0mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center}
 ]
 \addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates {(PC personal computer,52) (PML,5) (RR,0) (PN,42) };
```

*Result:*

```
    \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
   },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
xtick = data,
ytick={0,10,...,60},
enlarge y limits=0.0,
ymax=60,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
anchor=north,legend columns=-1}, 
ybar=5pt,
bar width=10pt, 
symbolic x coords={PC personal computer,PML,RR,PN},
ymajorgrids,
ticklabel style = {color=gray},% or opacity=0.5
axis line style={draw=none},
tick style={draw=none},
legend style={draw=none,text=gray},
xticklabels   = {PC personal computer, PML, RP, PN},
x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=north, inner sep=0mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center}
 ]
 \addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates {(PC personal computer,52) (PML,5) (RR,0) (PN,42) };
 \addplot[yellow,fill=yellow] coordinates {(PC personal computer,38) (PML,8) (RR,2) (PN,52) }; 
 \legend{A,B} 
 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=north east, inner sep=0mm,text width=1.5cm,align=center}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly for me. Now I'd like to explain those abbreviations (PC, PML, RR, etc), can you suggest me a way to do it and the related code? For example PC=personal computer, etc. I kind of second legend...
I can't use directly the complete descriptions under the x-axis in the graphic because they are too long.

Comment: Maybe something like this (with linebreak?) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51030/124842 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35886/124842

Comment: I prefer the first link you gave me, but I have two "items" (yellow and blue ones) for each value, so I don't understand how to do that. I have tried in different ways, but it doesn't work. Can you help me with the code?
Thanks

Comment: I added a update. I think you have to find your solution for your own... I hope it will help.