# Creating a bar chart with an ordinal x axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart where the values along the x axis are not relevant. My current code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\beging{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ylabel=Similarity,
                    ybar]
            \addplot table[y=Pref, col sep=comma] {5_Results/evalresults.csv};
            \addplot table[y=Rec, col sep=comma] {5_Results/evalresults.csv};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A bar chart of user and course similarity}
    \label{evalresultsbar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However this generates this chart. I'm not just looking to remove the values along the x axis, I also want to stop the bars from being stacked on top of each other.
[image]

My desired output would look something like this chart generated by google sheets:
[image]

The contents of evalresults.csv

```
Pref,Rec,label
0.00,14.29,a
0.00,16.67,a
0.00,16.67,a
0.00,20.00,a
0.00,20.00,a
0.00,25.00,a
0.00,33.33,a
0.00,33.33,a
0.00,33.33,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,60.00,a
0.00,60.00,a
0.00,60.00,a
33.33,25.00,a
33.33,25.00,a
33.33,33.33,a
33.33,33.33,a
33.33,60.00,a
33.33,60.00,a
33.33,66.67,a
33.33,75.00,a
33.33,75.00,a
33.33,75.00,a
33.33,80.00,a
33.33,80.00,a
33.33,100.00,a
66.67,75.00,a
66.67,80.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
100.00,100.00,a
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. `xtick=\empty` will remove the xticks. What does your data look like?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please convert your code snipped to complete small document with `\documentclass{...}` on it beginning and `\end{document}` on the end. For tests a `figure` is surplus.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the data is two columns of values, already sorted in ascending order in a .csv

Comment: See my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359221/124842 . You can use for example `bar width=1pt, ` for small bars and `ytick={0,10,...,100},`. You just have to add your data. If you need further help please add `evalresults.csv`.

Comment: And a separate x-column? Then you shouldn't see that stacking-effect your screenshot shows, which is why I asked.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've added the contents of the .csv to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the x-coordinate somehow, so add `x expr=\coordindex` in the options for `table`, as seen below.

I've added some comments in the code

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % for pgfplotstableread, but you can use the filename in the \addplot as you did instead
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Pref,Rec,label
0.00,14.29,a
0.00,16.67,a
0.00,16.67,a
0.00,20.00,a
0.00,20.00,a
0.00,25.00,a
0.00,33.33,a
0.00,33.33,a
0.00,33.33,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,50.00,a
0.00,60.00,a
0.00,60.00,a
0.00,60.00,a
33.33,25.00,a
33.33,25.00,a
33.33,33.33,a
33.33,33.33,a
33.33,60.00,a
33.33,60.00,a
33.33,66.67,a
33.33,75.00,a
33.33,75.00,a
33.33,75.00,a
33.33,80.00,a
33.33,80.00,a
33.33,100.00,a
66.67,75.00,a
66.67,80.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
66.67,100.00,a
100.00,100.00,a
}\data
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ylabel=Similarity,
  ybar,
  % reduce bar width
  bar width=1pt,
  % to remove whitespace below bars
  ymin=0,
  % only want the x-axis on the bottom
  axis x line=bottom,
  % add some horizontal space between bars and axis limits
  enlarge x limits=0.05,
  % don't draw the ticks
  tick style={draw=none},
  % remove x ticks
  xtick=\empty,
  % enable grid
  grid=major,
  % don't draw the vertical lines for the y-axes
  every outer y axis line/.style={draw=none},
  %position legend outside the axis, top right
  legend pos=outer north east,
  % don't draw box around legend
  legend style={draw=none}
]
    \addplot [fill=red!50,draw=none] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Pref, col sep=comma] {\data};
    \addplot [fill=blue!30,draw=none] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Rec, col sep=comma] {\data};

   \addlegendentry{Pref}
   \addlegendentry{Rec}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```