# How to remove the frame and keep the axis labels in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a simple pgfplots graph taken from [PGFPlots Gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis} 
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to remove the frame (the vertical line, the horizontal line and the dashes in these lines) but keep the xtick and ytick labels.

How can I do this?

NB. I am trying to produce [this image](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/visual-networking-index-vni/mobile-white-paper-c11-520862.doc/_jcr_content/renditions/mobile-white-paper-c11-520862_2.jpg) that's why I need to remove the frame:

[image]

Comment: Some hints at least can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367189/creating-a-bar-chart-with-an-ordinal-x-axis/367194#367194

Comment: Thank you. I need to add these two lines: `every outer y axis line/.style={draw=none}`  and `tick style={draw=none}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the `axis`-options. You can add:

```
  axis line style={draw=none},
  tick style={draw=none}
```

The second option removes the ticks too.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = {Exabytes\\ per month},
        ylabel style={align=center,rotate=-90},
    ]
        \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have also added the Y axis label with the line break.

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Bugger, too slow. Ah well, such is life. :D